# CURL library with VS Code and CMake?

Tags: visual-studio-code, curl, cmake

I've been trying to get the cURL library to cooperate with VS Code for quite sometime now and can't seem to find a working solution. Is it at all possible to use cURL with VS Code or should I just move over to Visual Studio Community and stop wasting my time with VS Code?

None of the described techiques here seem to be working on VS Code. The library just can't be included in a project without weird linker errors. Also, cURL has seemingly not implemented config files (CURLConfig.cmake or curl-config.cmake) for CMake, so find_package() and set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) don't work, because there's obviously nothing to find. I also tried installing and integrating cURL with vcpkg but that didn't help at all in VS Code despite the process going through succesfully. I also tried cloning the library directly to the VS Code project from Github and adding the required directories manually to a CMakeLists.txt file. That didn't help either.

Has anyone actually used succesfully the cURL library? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: To answer your first question. I doubt that the cURL library can't be used with CMake. Also VsCode is only a text editor what you're trying to achieve is to build your project with CMake. You can switch to Visual Studio Community if you want but you will face the same issue. And finally https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html 
CMake does provide a FindCurl.cmake which can be used with `find_package`.
Do you have installed the dev version of libcurl on your computer ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the dev version of the libcurl. I installed cURL on Windows10 with the vcpkg dependency manager as per instruction in here https://curl.se/docs/install.html. I had to to use the bootstrap-vcpkg.bat file instead of the bootstrap-vcpkg.sh file though to get this working. This method should have downloaded and built the needed files, if I understood correctly. I'm aware of the FindCURL module in CMake but for some reason it didn't seem to find anything about cURL. Maybe I used it incorrectly somehow?

Comment: Since you try to use the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, I think you used the find_package correctly. What compiler do you use to build your project ? I see on the instruction that you can only installed the lib for mingw32 but not for MSVC. If you try to use MSVC, CMake can't find the lib because there is no lib compatible with the MSVC compiler

Comment: I use MinGW64. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

<code>
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.0-rc1)

project(bitcoin)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} bitcoin.cpp json.hpp)

set(CURL_ROOT "C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl/src/url-7_84_0-fad13a6c94.clean")
find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
</code>

It tried to include cURL with <curl/curl.h>

Comment: The error message from CmakeTools: 

"CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):Could not find a package configuration file provided by \"CURL\" with any of\nthe following names:\n\n  CURLConfig.cmake\n  curl-config.cmake\n\nAdd the installation prefix of \"CURL\" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set\n\"CURL_DIR\" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If \"CURL\"\nprovides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been\ninstalled."

Comment: Most of the directions that I have come around seem to revolve around the Linux makefile utility. Is is so that the cURL library is actually incompatible with Windows, because Windows comes actually out of the box with a pre-installed cURL executable from Microsoft? In other words, I'm just wasting my time with this library.

Comment: I'm curious about why you use `find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED) ` instead of `find_package(CURL REQUIRED)`. It's true that CMake does not come with a CURLConfig.cmake so you can't use find_package in config mode. But you can use it in module mode because cmake come with a `FindCURL.cmake` file

Comment: I think that I read that somewhere from the Internet that I should use CURL CONFIG REQUIRED. I changed that now to CURL REQUIRED and CMake stopped complaining about the missing config file. However, now I get an error "curl/curl.h: No such file or directory" so apparently there is still something wrong with my path. I used the path where vcpkg installed curl ("C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl/src/url-7_84_0-fad13a6c94.clean"), but this is obviously somehow wrong?

Comment: Actually, there is an error in a targets.log file that claims that "make.exe all --print-data-base --no-builtin-variables --no-builtin-rules --question
'make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." So there is something weird going on with the CMakeTools too.

Comment: Oh that's strange. If CMAKE find CURL  your program should also be able to find `curl/curl.h`. Can you print the value of `CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS` in your CMake ?

Comment: Actually, I found out that this error went away simply after restarting VS Code, so it must have been some issue with caching or something. There was a new error however, CMake was complaining about the line "target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)", but I solved that by simply changing "main" to ${PROJECT_NAME}. Also I deleted the set(CURL_ROOT) variable statement. After this, I was able to configure and build the project succesfully.

Comment: However, while examining the CMake cache, I noticed that CURL_INCLUDE_DIR is "C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl/src/url-7_84_0-fad13a6c94.clean/include" but CURL_LIBRARY_RELEASE is "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/bin/libcurl.lib" which I find odd, because I understood that all the needed files were installed and maintained by vcpkg. I have added these in my environment paths too. There's also "C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl/x86-windows-rel/lib/libcurl.lib" but that doesn't seem to work for CMake for some reason. Also, VS Code is still complaining that curl/curl.h doesn't exist despite the success.

Comment: I was actually able to make that last error go away by adding the path "C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl" to variable CURL_DIR on the CMake cache file and just reconfiguring after that. Now, VS Code is complaining no more about the non-existent curl.curl.h. Still, if I try to use the libcurl.lib file from vcpkg instead of PostGres, I'll get an error from CMake with exit status 2.

Comment: An error from CMake ? What is the exact error ?

Comment: [main] Building folder: Project1 bitcoin
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build "e:/Cpp STL in Practice/Project1/build" --config Debug --target bitcoin -j 8 --
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target bitcoin
[build] [ 50%] Linking CXX executable bitcoin.exe

Comment: The a bunch of undefined references, which I don't include here. After that litany:
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\bitcoin.dir\build.make:100: bitcoin.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:123: bitcoin] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2

Comment: If I understood this correctly, the compilation is failing at the linking stage.

Comment: I find this very strange, because Vcpkg is advertised as an easy to use solution that provides automatic and flawless integration to Microsoft products (sarcasm intended).

Comment: Also, I think that there is something wrong, because I have understood, that you shouldn't normally have to touch the CMake Cache file.

Comment: FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE _DETAILS_CURL says: [C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/bin/libcurl.lib][C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl/src/url-7_84_0-fad13a6c94.clean/include][c ][v7.84.0-DEV()]

I suppose this is what is returned by find_package(CURL REQUIRED) statement in the CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: "I have understood, that you shouldn't normally have to touch the CMake Cache file" -> You are absolutely right. But You can provide the `CURL_DIR` variable at configuration. 

Yes I think it is what is returned by find_package. If vcpkg doesn't work, may be you should use an other approach like using `conan` instead.

Comment: I added now the statement 'set(CURL_DIR "C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl")' in my CMakeLists.txt file and now CMake doesn't try to find the libcurl.lib file anymore from PostGres installation but uses instead the Vcpkg installation like it should. I also had to reconfigure all to rewrite the cache file. Now there are no more weird references to PostGres, just to Vcpkg, so that seems right. However the build keeps still failing at linker stage. This time with a slighty different error though.

Comment: [build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build "e:/Cpp STL in Practice/Project1/build" --config Debug --target bitcoin -j 8 --
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/bitcoin.cpp.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable bitcoin.exe

For now everything seems right, it goes to 100%. But then starts the trouble. Once again a bunch of undefined references to various cURL functions.

Comment: And finally the error:
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\bitcoin.dir\build.make:100: bitcoin.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:123: bitcoin] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2

Comment: Here is the complete CMakeLists.txt file as of now: 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.0-rc1) 
project(bitcoin) 
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} bitcoin.cpp json.hpp)
set(CURL_DIR "C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl")
find_package(CURL REQUIRED) 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)

Comment: Also, CMake says while configuring:
[cmake] -- Found CURL: C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/curl/x86-windows-rel/lib/libcurl.lib (found version "7.84.0-DEV")  So this seems to work correctly.

Comment: Great to hear that it's finally find the CURL library. For the last error you got, there is too little information, I can't understand what's wrong with the log you have